# Difference in formatting between a bash command execution and a script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I don't understand why there is a difference in how the output is formatted on standard output for identical commands run from within a script and directly from the bash.

When I run `ls -l` from my bash command line I get a nice newline at the end of each file (resulting in a kind of a tabular data) while if the same command is run from bash via `$(ls -l)` I get the same data but on a single line.

If possible, please let me know how I can modify it (for the script).

Comment: It's probably to do with word splitting and how / when you quote your variables - but unless you share the relevant portion of your script it's a bit hard to say exactly

Answer (score 1):

When you use  `$(ls -l)` the newlines are removed.
It is made that way.

Same as `` `ls -l` `` which is identical to the preferred `$(ls -l)`.

When you want to do something with the output of `ls -l` you need to do it differently.

```bsh
ls -l |while read xx
do
   echo $xx
   ((ii = ii + 1))
done
```

(Be aware that this (`ls -l`) opens a new shell and variables set in that shell are not "visible" outside that shell so `ii` is not visible outside that loop.)